# Слабая связь между слоями приложения MVC

Tags: java, mvc, интерфейс

Делаю учебное задание - консольное приложение, реализующее MVC и Repository

```
.controller         - обработка действий пользователя
    .action         - действия пунктов меню
.model              - бизнес-логика приложения  
    .entity         - сущности приложения
    .repository     - подпакеты с интерфейсами и классами-хранилищами
    .service        - бизнес-логика приложения
.view               - отображение данных пользователю
```

Создал интерфейс, который обобщает все задачи бизнес-логики и имплементировал его классу-фасаду.
Хранилища и класс-фасад - Singleton, доступ к ним по getInstance.

При работе в action мне необходимо вызвать методы фасада.

```
IFasad fasad = Fasad.getInstance();
```

Преподаватель говорит, что в таком случае у меня пропадает слабая связь и контроллер знает реализацию фасада.

Аналогичная ситуация с репозиториями и сервисами сущностей.

```
IEntityReposytori reposytori = EntityReposytory.getInstance();
```

Подскажите правильный вариант реализации взаимодействия между слоями.

Comment: Какие ещё вы знаете способы издания объектов?

Comment: нужно IFasad fasad  передавать через конструктор

Answer (score 0):

Что значит слабая связь? Это когда один объект не знает ничего о другом объекте, только об интерфейсе.

- Сильная связь

  К примеру вы можете написать такой код:

  ```
  ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
  strings.add("Hello");
  ```

  Вы создали конкретный класс `ArrayList` и теперь ваш класс знает о конкретной реализации `ArrayList`. Чем это чревато? К примеру завтра вы решили что вам больше не подходит `ArrayList`, а нужен `LinkedList`. Вам придется идти и менять код на

  ```
  LinkedList<String> anotherStrings = new LinkedList<>();
  anotherStrings.add("Hello");
  ```

  Казалось бы ничего страшного, поменяли 1 строку. Теперь представим что вы передаете этот `ArrayList` еще в 5-10 других методов как параметр и везде вы в функции указываете `ArrayList` как аргумент функции:

  ```
  public void soneMethod(ArrayList<String> list){
      // some code
  }
  ```

  Так вот когда вы захотите использовать `LinkedList` вам придется поменять его во всех функциях в которых есть ваш `ArrayList`.
- Слабая связь

  ```
  List<String> anotherStrings = new ArrayList<>();
  anotherStrings.add("Hello");
  ```

  И пример ваших функций который принимают на вход ваш список

  ```
  public void soneMethod(List<String> list){
      // some code
  }
  ```

  Если завтра вам понадобится `LinkedList` то вам придется поменять только 1 строку кода и все остальное работает.

  ```
  List<String> anotherStrings = new LinkedList<>();
  ```

  Почему? Потому что весь ваш код зависит от только от интерфейса `List`. А это значит, что вашему коду все равно что вы там напишете лишь бы оно реализовывало интерфейс `List`: `ArrayDeque<E>`, `ReversedList<T>` и т.д.

  А еще в более серьезных проектах используется DI (Внедрение зависимостей) где то как будет создаваться объект указано только в одном месте, а значит что если ваш код использует какую-то зависимость только от интерфейса и вам вдруг надо подменить один объект на другой, то вы меняете это в одном месте и весь проект продолжает работать.
- Что еще не хватает вам? Объекты одного класса не должны создаваться внутри другого класса (но без фанатизма, какие-то вещи все же создаются внутри класса).

  Возьмем ваш случай. У вас условно есть `class Controller`

  ```
  class Controller { 

      IEntityReposytori reposytori = EntityReposytory.getInstance();

      // some code
  }
  ```

  Внутри вашего контроллера вы создаете явный экземпляр `EntityReposytory`, а значит, что ваш `Controller` зависит от `EntityReposytory`, вы не сможете подменить его в тестах или динамически при создании контроллера т.к. это внутрення реализация класса `Controller`.

  Что можно сделать? Можно передавать `IEntityReposytori` в конструкторе, например так:

  ```
  class Controller { 

      IEntityReposytori reposytori;

      Controller (IEntityReposytori reposytori){
          this.reposytori = reposytori;
      }

      // some code
  }
  ```

  Что нам это даст? Так вы можете подменять объект вашего репозитория в рантайме динамически. Пример:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Controller controller;
      if (debug){
          controller = Controller(DebugRepository.getInstance());
      } else {
          controller = Controller(ProductionRepository.getInstance());
      }
  }
  ```

  Внутри класс будет работать независимо от того, что вы ему передадите, главное чтоб это "что-то" реализовало интерфейс `IEntityReposytori`.

Почитайте [эту](https://medium.com/@xufocoder/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-de1367295ba8) статью. Там неплохо объясняется, что такое "Внедрение зависимостей".

Так же рекомендую почитать серию статей про `Dagger`. Вы можете не читать все, если слово `Dagger` для вас звучит, как что-то дикое, но вот первые 3 прочесть стоит, там общие понятия и примеры:

- [Dagger 2 для начинающих разработчиков — Введение](https://habr.com/ru/post/343248/)
- [Dagger 2 для начинающих разработчиков. Внедрение зависимостей. Часть 1](https://habr.com/ru/post/343250/)
- [Dagger 2 для начинающих разработчиков. Внедрение зависимостей. Часть 2](https://habr.com/ru/post/343658/)